# Having trouble running magento

Tags: javascript, php, database, magento, exception

How to resolve this, however I am trying to install **Magento** on my server. I have exported all files from different server to my server, and I am getting this error.
 Is this due to symlinks that i have created or something else?

1 exception(s):

```
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): Invalid method Smartwave\Filterproducts\Block\FeaturedList\Interceptor::isHomePage
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento setup:di:compile
php -d memory_limit=-1 -f bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
```